# Is it possible to make a HEAD request in puppeteer?

Tags: http-headers, puppeteer, http-head

I have not been able to find documentation that addresses this. I want to grab header data for some links to text files to determine which are recent, but I don't want to download each file to find out this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I couldn't make a HEAD request directly from puppeteer, but I can use node's https library in conjunction with puppeteer to make a HEAD request. This [very informative article](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/download-file-puppeteer/) helped me arrive at a solution.

```js
import https from 'https';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function downloadWithLinks() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true // false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(
        'https://unsplash.com/photos/tn57JI3CewI',
        { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }
    );
    const imgUrl = await page.$eval('.tB6UZ', img => img.src);

    https.request(imgUrl, {method: 'HEAD'}, res=> {console.log(res.headers)}).end()
    browser.close()
}
```